# how to fix my copy data range into other files in app script google

Tags: google-apps-script

i have to copy my sheet from file1 (16aWONG-TyHYxYFYqfDI7Pw2PVuNvDQ0cnFoIv_SDA4U) into file2 (1zIeqvQuC7RlXy9SB--SaNaEXKT399NvffM3F3nfAXGs)
i have this script, but it didnt work, i don't know where to put fromfile

```
function getdata() {
    var files = DriveApp.getFileById("1zIeqvQuC7RlXy9SB--SaNaEXKT399NvffM3F3nfAXGs").getFiles()
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      var shoot = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
      
      var sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("BahanMix");
      var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange('A:D');
      var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();
      
    var destsheet = shoot.getSheetByName('Sheet23'); 
    var destrange = destsheet.getRange('A:D'); 
    destrange.setValues(sourcevalues);         
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stick with the `spreadsheet app` versus using drive as your initial code operates on. I think you can get what you want with this below code. I included a check to ensure the row count is the same.

```
function getDate() {
  var fromFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById("16aWONG-TyHYxYFYqfDI7Pw2PVuNvDQ0cnFoIv_SDA4U");
  var targetFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1zIeqvQuC7RlXy9SB--SaNaEXKT399NvffM3F3nfAXGs");

  var sourcesheet = fromFile.getSheetByName("BahanMix");
  var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange('A:D');
  var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();
      
  var destsheet = targetFile.getSheetByName('Sheet23'); 
  var destrange = destsheet.getRange('A:D');
  //make sure the same number or rows exist
  if (destsheet.getMaxRows()!= sourcesheet.getMaxRows()){
    Browser.msgBox("Row MisMatch. Destination has " + 
    destsheet.getMaxRows() + " rows while source has " +
    sourcesheet.getMaxRows()) + " rows."
  }else{
  destrange.setValues(sourcevalues);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for help, its get little error that number of row must be exactly same. How about it doesn't look at the row length ?

Comment: Unfortunately, if you're pushing more than one value to google sheets, than you have to have the exact number of rows and columns. Thanks for accepting.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `getActive()` your script is bound to your source spreadsheet, so `SpreadsheetApp` can be used directly to open files.

```
function getdata() {
    var shoot = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1zIeqvQuC7RlXy9SB--SaNaEXKT399NvffM3F3nfAXGs");
      
    var sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("BahanMix");
    var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange('A:D');
    var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();
      
    var destsheet = shoot.getSheetByName('Sheet23'); 
    var destrange = destsheet.getRange('A:D'); 
    destrange.setValues(sourcevalues);         
}
```